# How to recover data deleted using truncate in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, restore, truncate, cassandra-3.0

I have accidentally truncated a table in Cassandra. I would like to know whether there is any tool available to restore data in it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: if `snapshot_before_compaction` is TRUE in cassandra.yaml then you might have snapshot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> auto_snapshot  (Default: true)
>
> Whether Cassandra takes a snapshot of
> the data before truncating a keyspace or dropping a table. To prevent
> data loss, DataStax strongly advises using the default setting. If you
> set auto_snapshot to false, data loss occurs on truncation or drop.

(taken from https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html)

If you are in luck, look into the snapshot directories for your old sstables. For restoring they "only" need to be copied back to their original locations.

Here is what happens:

```
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/backups
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/mc-1-big-Data.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/mc-1-big-Index.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/mc-1-big-Filter.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/mc-1-big-Summary.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/mc-1-big-Digest.crc32
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/mc-1-big-CompressionInfo.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/mc-1-big-Statistics.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/mc-1-big-TOC.txt
```

Then I issued `TRUNCATE demokeyspace.demo` - after that it is something like this:

```
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/backups
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/snapshots
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/snapshots/truncated-1527228644868-demo
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/snapshots/truncated-1527228644868-demo/mc-1-big-Summary.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/snapshots/truncated-1527228644868-demo/mc-1-big-TOC.txt
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/snapshots/truncated-1527228644868-demo/mc-1-big-Digest.crc32
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/snapshots/truncated-1527228644868-demo/mc-1-big-Filter.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/snapshots/truncated-1527228644868-demo/mc-1-big-CompressionInfo.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/snapshots/truncated-1527228644868-demo/mc-1-big-Index.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/snapshots/truncated-1527228644868-demo/mc-1-big-Data.db
./data1/demokeyspace/demo-0d1a38b05fe211e8875d13cbb58d64f2/snapshots/truncated-1527228644868-demo/mc-1-big-Statistics.db
```

Simply copy those files back. But keep in mind that you need to do this on all nodes and run `nodetool refresh demokeyspace demo` afterwards to reread the tables (of course with your keyspace and columnfamily).